# A pop that disables parent window

Tags: html

I know how to show a pop-up window. But I will like to freeze or disable the parent window when there is a pop-up window active. Once the pop-up window is closed, the parent window should automatically be active again.

How exactly is it done?

Comment: He said modal dialog! Stone him! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not neet o remake the wheel.
Take a look at [this page](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos).

It's a JQuery plugin that does exactly what you ask, and much much more.

Answer (score 0):

It is just my personal idea, but I would think, the solution could be when open the pop up windows, you just override the click function of the parent document to return false, and set it back to normal when they close the pop up window, some JavaScript code will need to be used here

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a modal dialog box? Most of these disable the parent window by positioning an overlay... Here is a list of [22 different plugins](http://www.blogrammierer.de/jquery-die-22-besten-modal-fenster-plugins/) ( you don't need to read German to use this site :P )